# How Thunderbird email client is able to access Outlook emails via IMAP

Tags: authentication, office365, imap

Microsoft has disabled Basic Auth some time ago when trying to authenticate and access emails via IMAP. We all should use OAuth instead. But ThunderBird is somehow able to access all my emails just by providing email address and password when configuring email account.

How does it do it? Does it somehow perform OAuth under the hood? If yes, how does it know tenant id, client id and client secret? Or does it use some other technique like actually login into Outlook account and somehow get the emails..

I would like to be able to do it the same way in my code just by providing email address and password.

Answer (score 0):

They blocked everything that sends a password over the wire (so that a snooping third party could learn the password). There are several ways to authenticate where the server sends the client a challenge, the client uses the password to solve the challenge, and the server checks the client's response.

Make your client report which IMAP capabilities are supported. The ones called `AUTH=…` are relevant, and you want to implement a few with names containin `SHA1`, `DIGEST`, `SCRAM`, `CRAM`, that kind of phrase. Look at the ones advertised by important servers and find the RFCs for each. If the RFC says "challenge response", it's fine.